# rustlings: hashmap3.rs expected `()`, found struct `Team`

Tags: rust, rust-rustlings

I'm learning rust using rustlings. I was trying to implement a solution in a functional way (rustlings only asked for the imperative way). I'm running into the following compiler error and haven't been able to figure this out since 2 hours. Please help

### Compiler error:

```rust
Progress: [############################>-------------------------------] 45/94
! Compiling of exercises/hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs failed! Please try again. Here's the output:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> exercises/hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs:94:28
   |
94 |           .and_modify(|team| Team {
   |  ____________________________^
95 | |             name: team.name.to_string(),
96 | |             goals_scored: team.goals_scored+team_from_iter.goals_scored,
97 | |             goals_conceded: team.goals_conceded+team_from_iter.goals_conceded,
98 | |         })
   | |_________^ expected `()`, found struct `Team`       

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

### Code

This is the set of lines the compiler has an issue with

```rust
.and_modify(|team| Team {
    name: team.name.to_string(),
    goals_scored: team.goals_scored+team_from_iter.goals_scored,
    goals_conceded: team.goals_conceded+team_from_iter.goals_conceded,
})
```

### Link to full code repo:

1. To the exact lines with the issue: https://github.com/dheerajbhaskar/learn-rust-rustlings-PUBLIC/blob/a3d38c643fc178f05a847e7cb8016a784b0a54ac/exercises/hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs#L94-L98
2. To the repo: https://github.com/dheerajbhaskar/learn-rust-rustlings-PUBLIC

### Additional information

1. I've written very similar code on [line 119](https://github.com/dheerajbhaskar/learn-rust-rustlings-PUBLIC/blob/a3d38c643fc178f05a847e7cb8016a784b0a54ac/exercises/hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs#L119) which compiles and passes the tests. I've not been able to understand why that worked but code at line 94 above didn't. Edit: looks like I've compiler error both these lines now ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
2. I'm a rust noob if it wasn't apparent yet :)

Comment: What is the signature of the `and_modify` function? It seems to be expecting your callback to return nothing

Comment: Oh! I think I might've mixed up return of the closure to the return of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> pub fn and_modify<F>(self, f: F) -> Self
> where
>     F: FnOnce(&mut V),
> ```

[`and_modify`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.and_modify)'s argument has the type `FnOnce(&mut V)`. This is a function that takes a single argument of type `&mut V` and returns nothing. (If it were returning something it would have a signature like `FnOnce(&V) -> V` instead.)

Concretely, you're receiving a mutable `Team` object that's already in the hash map and you're expected to modify it in place. Instead of constructing a brand new `Team` you should update the team that you're being passed. Something like this, say:

```
.and_modify(|team| {
    team.goals_scored += team_from_iter.goals_scored;
    team.goals_conceded += team_from_iter.goals_conceded;
})
```

Notice how this modifies `team` in place and doesn't return anything.